# Login using DB and Social website

Tags: java, facebook, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have a carpool website where users can log in through my DB and everything is working fine.

Once logged in, users can post advertisements for carpooling.

Now my need is for users to log in through Facebook. How is such a scenario handled?

Case 1: User is not registered with my DB and used Facebook credentials. I can show pages which are read-only, but say now the user wants to post an ad, what do I do in this case?

My DB is structured in such a way that the postAd table has user_id as foreign key, so in this case should I add a user with that email_id and a dummy password to allow them to post? Or how are such scenarios handled?

Case 2: If user logs in using Facebook do I need to search in my DB with that email id to find that user?

I am using Spring Security.

How does such a website generally work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) and [Spring Social Facebook](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/) projects. They do:

1. For Case 1: there is [Implicit sign up feature](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html#signin_signup_implicit). You must provide ConnectionSignUp implementation that will be called when FB connection is established but there is no corresponding user in DB. You can create new DB user here.
2. For Case 2: there is a SignInAdapter interface (see [ProviderSignInController's dependencies](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html#d4e851)
   chapiter). You can find DB user by userId then prepare autentication and inject it into SecurityContextHolder.

Genral idea: you can have multiple providers (FB, Twitter, etc...) but in any case each social profile will be matched to some Spring Security user (that will be used for authorization for example). If they match by userId then you can have one Spring Security user for multiple social accounts.
Advantage of this approach is that you will have more control over user profile (you can disable local user account even if FB account is active). You can use Facebook API from java code.

As a option 2 you can do FB login via JavaScript. Then implement two features for Case 1 and Case 2 manually (for example via custom filter). It may be more lightweight (depends on what features do you need).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Oauth provides a unique userid for each user. so, if a user sign in using facebook its better to store the details of the user such as id,name,email etc..in user table.so,you can use that userid as a primary key ... If the user already exists jsut skip this part and take them to post page..